# iPhone and photo management on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, iphoto, picasa

I have just switched from Windows to Mac as my iTunes sync partner for my iPhone.

On the Windows box, I used to get it to import/delete the pic from the phone into a directory and then that same directory was sync'd back onto the iphone.

On the Mac, I could sync the photos using iPhoto, but I prefer (not sure why...) to keep my photos outside of iPhoto.  I keep my photos on my iDisk, so they backed up in the cloud.

Perhaps Picasa could extract the photos from the iPhone?

Or maybe I should setup a iPhoto library on the iDisk and so gain the benefit of the backups and goodies of iPhoto.

What do you do?

Thanks in advance for any tips,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the photes using Image Capture, a tool that lives in your Applications folder.
In here you can choose to extract to a folder instead of iPhoto.

But, it won't sync back, say if you erase something in one folder.

In Image captures preferences (In the menu called Image Capture) you can also choose what happens when you connect the iPhone. Here, for instance, you could change it to, "Open Image Capture" then that will be the default action.

I have mine set to "No Application", then you can choose yourself which you want to open.

Hope this helps.
//Ulrik

Comment: Gonna try this, importing to my iDisk - I can get iTunes to sync back the specified folder... annoying the sync complains about iTunes locking the files, or so it seems.. but it is a first sync

Answer (score 3):

I recommend setting up an iPhoto libary on the iDisk, i have been using that setup for a while and i have no complaints